# Why won't my NSView draw something on click?

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsview

On a custom NSView I made, I overriden the mouseDown method this way :

```
override func mouseDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {
let location = self.convertPoint(theEvent.locationInWindow, fromView: nil)
NSColor.blackColor().set()
let basisRect = CGRect(origin: location, size: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10))
let roundPath = NSBezierPath(ovalInRect: basisRect)
roundPath.fill()
needsDisplay = true 
}
```

But I doesn't draw anything when I click *(even if the `mouseDown` method is triggered as I checked with a println())*

Have you any idea of why nothing happens and how to fix it ?

**EDIT (here's my drawRect function) :**

```
  override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.drawRect(dirtyRect)
        NSColor.blackColor().set()
        let middlePoint = (self.bounds.size.width/2)
        let basisRect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: middlePoint-5, y: 10), size: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10))
        let roundPath = NSBezierPath(ovalInRect: basisRect)
        roundPath.fill()

        let bottomLegPath = NSBezierPath()
        bottomLegPath.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: middlePoint, y: 10))
        bottomLegPath.lineToPoint(CGPoint(x: middlePoint, y: middlePoint))
        bottomLegPath.lineWidth = 5
        bottomLegPath.stroke()

        }
```

Thank you.

Comment: when you call `super.drawRect()` all your drawings in `mouseDown()` is gone away.

Answer (score 4):

An NSView draws by calling `drawRect:`. Only what is in `drawRect:` matters. You do not show your `drawRect:` code, but I am betting you don't have any. That is where you need to draw your round path, not in the `mouseDown` implementation.

Comment: I updated with my drawRect function, I had something but it didn't changed in function of mouseDown events.

Comment: Right, that's the problem. You need to put some info from `mouseDown` in a place where `drawRect` can get it, so that when `drawRect` draws again, it draws your round path where you want it.